# Why is Array.prototype also an Array?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I thought every prototype should be an object.

why?

Array.isArray( Array.prototype ) // true

[developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype) explains nothing

Comment: Arrays are objects

Comment: @Quentin and what? if you would say "objects are arrays" it does make sense, else it not

Comment: I would say that array is an array. The prototype of it is an array, where is the problem ?

Comment: @VladimirStarkov — All arrays are objects. Not all objects are arrays.

Comment: Have a look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work

Comment: @nicolallias  i don't understand from that answer why array.prototype is array and not object

Answer (score 5):

Your assumption that every prototype is an `Object` is not correct.

```
console.log(String.prototype)
console.log(Number.prototype)
console.log(Boolean.prototype)
console.log(Array.prototype)
console.log(Object.prototype)
```

Output:

```
String {}
Number {}
Boolean {}
[]
Object {}
```

From the [ECMAScript Language Specification - 15.4.4 Properties of the Array Prototype Object](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4) (emphasis mine)

> The value of the [[Prototype]] internal property of the Array prototype object is the standard built-in Object prototype object (15.2.4).
>
> **The Array prototype object is itself an array**; its [[Class]] is "Array", and it has a length property (whose initial value is +0) and the special [[DefineOwnProperty]] internal method described in 15.4.5.1.

Comment: it is an fact, but _why?_

Comment: @VladimirStarkov Because that's what the spec dictates. A question to you, why not? Why do you expect it to be `Object`?

Comment: can you give me a link to this spec?

Comment: @Stijn Because it would be less confusing if it were not an array and just an object, there has to be a reason for it. Those guys just don't go around designing stuff just because "why the hell not ?".

Comment: @Taurus looking back, I don't think this is a good answer. Unfortunately we can only speculate. It may have something to do with arrays not being included in the first prototype of JS, which was designed in 10 days ([source](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/standard)).

Comment: It is not specific to arrays though, functions are like that as well. In the specs, the reason is said to be:
_The Function prototype object is specified to be a function object to ensure compatibility with ECMAScript code that was created prior to the ECMAScript 2015 specification._ (this also applies to arrays) That's the why. However, it leads to another why, "Why did ECMAScript code that was created prior to the ECMAScript 2015 specification have Function.prototype as an empty function ?". It is all disappointing really, things should be clearer than that.

Comment: @VladimirStarkov Here's the spec: https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-262/. Note though that the spec is not easy to read. It is not written from the point of view of defining the behaviour of the language. Instead it is written from the point of view of someone wanting to implement javascript in C++. Part of this is because the spec was written mainly for the benefit of web browser developers. Part of it is because the spec evolved from the original implementation of javascript in Netscape Navigator.

Answer (score 0):

Try typing this into your javascript console:
`typeof Array.prototype;`

The `Array.prototype` is actually an Array. Which is detailed on this page.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype

It probably has something to do with the Fact that `[]` is shorthand for `Array`.

So `Array.prototype` points to `[]`.
`Array.prototype.constructor` points to `function Array() { [native code] }`

`[].constructor` also points to `function Array() { [native code] }`

So at a guess, it is done this way so that you can user `Array` and `[]` interchangably.

I dont know for sure this is the reason, but thats my best guess.

Comment: your answer explains nothing

Comment: @VladimirStarkov I have fixed that. It now explains something. I should have done that from the start. Thanks for calling me out and making me put an actual answer.

Comment: it is strange to me that "Which is detailed on this page" is equal to  "Little known fact:"

Comment: Well .. it IS detailed on the page. No reason for it to be strange.

Comment: Yes, but there is no explanation why it is so

Comment: No there isnt. Its surprising. Anyway, below the link I put my best guess. Thats all I know :)

Answer (score -1):

But just trying to contribute however I can.

The `prototype` is meant to add on functionality/capabilities to all Javascript objects, of which Array is a Javascript object. However, arrays are a special kind of object.

If you checked the `typeof` for Arrays, it will reflect as object. ([Source 1](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp#:%7E:text=Arrays%20are%20Objects,are%20best%20described%20as%20arrays.))

However, end of the day, you should think of them as Arrays ([]) and not objects per se ({}). So an array is a special kind of object, and because it's a JS object, it has access to `prototype` which allows it to have access to new methods and properties. ([Source 2](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_prototype_array.asp))

This is based on my rudimentary research and understanding.