# Where does the Array.prototype functions come from?

Tags: javascript

Since `Array.prototype` itself returns an empty array, where do all functions come from?

Why I can call functions something like `Array.prototype.sort`, even Array.prototype is not object?

`Array.prototype.__proto__` is an object.

I have same question on the case of `Function.prototype`.

Comment: Why do you think `Array.prototype` is not an object? Arrays (and functions) are both objects in JS.

Answer (score 2):

`Array.prototype` is an object, and most functions you used for array come from it. So it's the **prototype**.

Open chrome dev bar, and check it like the below image.

[image]

Comment: +1 for `console.debug` (unfortunately not standard). Complementing: `Array.prototype.sort` does not show in `console.log` because it's not [enumerable property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Description). Check with `Array.prototype.propertyIsEnumerable("sort")`. `console.log` implementation uses [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), and, as pointed in the docs, *The Object.keys() method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable properties*

Comment: Thank you for your comment, xdazz. Yes, I checked on chrome console  and I got a question. It says Array[0] or [] when you call `Array.prototype`.  `Array.isArray(Array.prototype)` returns true. Array is one of the built-in objects so that it is object.

Answer (score 0):

> even `Array.prototype` is not object?

How did you get that idea? It is an object:

```
typeof Array.prototype // "object"
```

As such it can have properties like every other object. And it does:

```
Array.prototype.hasOwnProperty("sort") // true
Array.prototype.sort // function(compare) { … }
```

This is the same for every other array, you can create custom properties on them like on every javascript object:

```
var foo = [];
foo.bar = "baz";
typeof foo.bar // "string"
Array.isArray(foo) // true
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

Yes `typeof Array.prototype` returns "object" but `Array.isArray(Array.prototype)` returns also true which means it is array natives, isn't it? How can the functions be retrived from array.?

Comment: Every array is just an object with a special-behaving `length` property (and possibly some engine optimisations), but a standard js object in every other regard.

Comment: I see. Why `Array.prototype` is not contained plain key/value object instead of array or function. Using array as key/value hash table sounds not good practice..

Comment: That's a different question with [a simple but unsatisfying answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23652338/why-array-prototype-is-an-array#comment36327185_23652488) :-)

Comment: Ahh, thank you for sharing it. I am confused because I did not expect javascript uses array for hashtable-like purpose..  Thank you for all your comments.

Comment: Not necessarily for the *purpose*, but it offers the possibility. It's just that everything is just a specialisation of objects, and properties on arrays, functions, regexes etc work exactly like on plain objects when assigning, inheriting etc.